# Change brush size for trees in Unity terrain

Tags: unity-game-engine

How would I change the size of the tree brush tool used on a Unity terrain. Other terrain tools have a brush size slider, but this is not shown.

[image]

Comment: it's right there!  look again!  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out the reason no Brush Size slider or other settings was shown was because no tree was selected above the "Edit Trees..." button. Not only must trees be added, a tree must be clicked and highlighted for the settings to appear. It's an odd situation for trees to be present and none selected, but I believe this is a side effect of using TerrainComposer to initially place trees.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Slider is present there! Look again

[image]